# mosaic plot with two variables

Tags: r, mosaic-plot, r-mosaic

This time i am struggling with plotting a mosaic plot. I have 9 town districts and in every district individuals were scored health score 1 or health score 2+3. I want to visualise this in a plot but i can't seem to get it to work.

My dataset:

```
> dput(THSWP1_23)
structure(list(`Town District` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
`health score 1` = c(50, 236, 215, 277, 261, 333, 414, 385, 
358), `Health score 2 and 3` = c(51, 238, 218, 281, 266, 
339, 421, 393, 367)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I have tried:

```
mosaicplot(THSWP1_23, main = "Test")
```

which resulted in: [image: Mosaic plot dataset]

But the Town districts are part of the boxes and i want to plot a square for health score 1 and health score 2+3 with town district on the x-axis.

then i tried

```
> count <- table(THSWP1_23$`health score 1`,THSWP1_23$`Health score 2 and 3`)
> mosaicplot(count)
```

with the result: [image: mosaic plot]

I tried again with a different count.

```
> count <- table(THSWP1_23$`Town District`,THSWP1_23$`health score 1`,THSWP1_23$`Health score 
2 and 3`)
> mosaicplot(count)
> mosaicplot(THSWP1_23$`health score 1`~THSWP1_23$`Health score 2 and 3`,data=THSWP1_23)
```

with the result: [image: mosaic again]

hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be creating a stacked bar plot or facet bars by first converting your data to longer format using `pivot_longer` and after that use `geom_col` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
THSWP1_23 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`health score 1`:`Health score 2 and 3`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = factor(`Town District`))) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```r
THSWP1_23 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`health score 1`:`Health score 2 and 3`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = factor(`Town District`))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~`Town District`)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>